# there is no default persistence unit in this deployment

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

i recieve the error below after creating a new EJB bean:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Illegal @PersistenceUnit on private javax.persistence.EntityManager com.mgt.ejb.session.dao.directdebit.PWDDIDetailsDAOBean.mEntityManager: There is no default persistence unit in this deployment.    
    at org.jboss.injection.PersistenceContextHandler.handleFieldAnnotations(PersistenceContextHandler.java:182)
    at org.jboss.injection.InjectionUtil.processFieldAnnotations(InjectionUtil.java:136)
    at org.jboss.injection.InjectionUtil.processAnnotations(InjectionUtil.java:173)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer.processMetadata(EJBContainer.java:270)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.SessionContainer.processMetadata(SessionContainer.java:116)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.processEJBContainerMetadata(Ejb3Deployment.java:273)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.start(Ejb3Deployment.java:322)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Module.startService(Ejb3Module.java:91)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)    
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)     
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy26.start(Unknown Source)   
    at org.jboss.ejb3.EJB3Deployer.start(EJB3Deployer.java:449)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor177.invoke(Unknown Source)    
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy27.start(Unknown Source)   
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1015)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor52.invoke(Unknown Source)     
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy9.deploy(Unknown Source)   
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.deploy(URLDeploymentScanner.java:421)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.scan(URLDeploymentScanner.java:634)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner$ScannerThread.doScan(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:263)
    at org.jboss.deployment.scanner.AbstractDeploymentScanner.startService(AbstractDeploymentScanner.java:336)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:289)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:978)
    at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)    
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:417)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)     
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:86)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)    
    at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:302)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:1025)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:819)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:782)
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:766)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)  
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:155)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:94)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
    at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:210)
    at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)   
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:482)
    at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:362)
    at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:200)
    at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:490)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my staleless bean:

```
package com.mgt.ejb.session.dao.directdebit;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


import com.mgt.ejb.entity.directdebit.DDIDetails;
import com.mgt.ejb.session.dao.GenericDAO;
import com.mgt.util.MGtLogger;
import com.mgt.util.exception.DAOException;

@Stateless
public class PWDDIDetailsDAOBean extends GenericDAO implements
        PWDDIDetailsDAOController {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager mEntityManager;

    private final Logger mLogger = MGtLogger
            .getLogger(PWDDIDetailsDAOBean.class);


    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mEntityManager;
    }


    public DDIDetails findByDDIDetailsId(long aDDIDetailsId)
            throws DAOException {

        DDIDetails lMethod = null;

        try {
            Query lQuery = mEntityManager
                    .createNamedQuery("DDIDetails.findByDDIDetailsId");
            lQuery.setParameter("ddIDetailsId", aDDIDetailsId);
            lMethod = (DDIDetails) lQuery.getSingleResult();

        } catch (NoResultException eX) {
            lMethod = null;
        }

        return lMethod;
    }


    public Collection<DDIDetails> findByPaymentMethodId(long aPaymentMethodId)
            throws DAOException {
        Collection<DDIDetails> lMethods = null;
        try {
            Query lQuery = mEntityManager
                    .createNamedQuery("DDIDetails.findByDDIDetailsId");
            lQuery.setParameter("paymentMethodId", aPaymentMethodId);
            lMethods = lQuery.getResultList();

        } catch (NoResultException eX) {
            lMethods = new ArrayList<DDIDetails>();
        }

        return lMethods;
    }

}
```

And here is my persistence.xml file:

```
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns:persistence="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="PWPTE">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
        </provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:datasource/profile5</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.mgt.ejb.entity.directdebit.DDIDetails</class>
        <class>com.mgt.ejb.entity.directdebit.DDIDetailsLog</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect"
                value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

here is my ejb-jar.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar version="3.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>PTE EJBs</display-name>
    <enterprise-beans>
        <session>
            <ejb-name>PTELogic</ejb-name>
            <remote>com.mgt.ejb.session.ptewrapper.PTEController</remote>
            <ejb-class>com.mgt.ejb.session.ptewrapper.PTELogic</ejb-class>
        </session>
        <session>
            <ejb-name>PWDDIDetailsDAO</ejb-name>
            <remote>com.mgt.ejb.session.dao.directdebit.PWDDIDetailsDAOController</remote>
            <ejb-class>com.mgt.ejb.session.dao.directdebit.PWDDIDetailsDAOBean</ejb-class>
        </session>
        <session>
            <ejb-name>PWDDIDetailsLogDAO</ejb-name>
            <remote>com.mgt.ejb.session.dao.directdebit.PWDDIDetailsLogDAOController</remote>
            <ejb-class>com.mgt.ejb.session.dao.directdebit.PWDDIDetailsLogDAOBean</ejb-class>
        </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
    <ejb-client-jar/>
</ejb-jar>
```

Im not sure where im going wrong here. i am using Jboss 4.0.5

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is your persistence.xml located?

Comment: do you have an .ear and inside of that an EJB .jar?

Comment: Yes ihave a ejb-jar.xml file there. let me post the contents of it

Comment: i think i found out the issue. the build.xml was missing the entry point for the persistence.xml file